# I am new to golang, I am trying to create a zip that must have a folder inside that is: tosend.zip/archivos/file.png

Tags: go, zip

```
newZip, err := os.Create("./temp/tosend.zip")
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
defer newZip.Close()

zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(newZip)
_, err = zipWriter.Create("archivos/")
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
defer zipWriter.Close()
```

Comment: ZIP files don't have folders as a separate entry, i.e. you cannot create a directory in zip. But they might have files which have a path with new folders which will then create the needed directories when extracting with the right options.

Comment: What does the code in your question do so far? Is there an error? Unexpected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.  A file name can contain directories. 
 Use this code:

```
zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(newZip)
w, err := zipWriter.Create("archivos/file.png") // <-- use full path here
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
w.Write(pngData)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/W7AcgBI3Tcl).

Comment: thank you very much, it worked just the way i wanted it